# Just Loaded Trusty tahr where is the update manager

Tags: updates, printing

I have just loaded Trusty Tahr but the update manager link in the far right dropdown menu (my previous version of Ubuntu (12.04) at least shows 'Software Up to Date' and looking in the dash screen it is not listed as an installed package. So how do I do updates?

Also I have a new Epson printer (XP412) and I have installed the driver for it. It is a wifi printer but also has a USB input. But when I try to add the printer (switched on and connected) it asks for: LPT , Enter URI, and link to Network Printer How can I install a USB print. Normally I would expect it to find it automatically

Comment: two mutually exclusive questions. Might it be better to split them into two separate postings for better coverage?

Comment: Call it from terminal and lock to launcher

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE MANAGER LINK QUESTION:

Select the search icon  (top left) in the sidebar (launcher) and type `updater`.

You will be presented with the software updater icon.

Select this and notice the icon is available in the left hand panel. Right click on the icon and select `Lock to Launcher` and voila!

You can select the various options you require by selecting `Software & Updates` from System Settings.

[image]

[image]

When there are updates, the colour of the icon background changes to green to alert you.

Comment: Those are the settings I have.
I couldn't find the update manager in the dash list
I could run update-manager from command line using sudo update-manager but no 'system up to date' or equivalent in the control drop down menu or a link to a list of files that need to be updated.